# mongoDB best practice: microservices with independent data stores

Tags: mongodb, microservices

A common pattern for microservices is that each should reference an independent data store.  To that end, I am planning on allocating a single mongoDB instance, but provisioning a separate database for each microservice (all databases, that is, co-located within the same mongoDB instance).

This partitions the data store by microservice, but also introduces potential contention issues (over network bandwidth, connection limits to mongoDB, etc).

Is there a best practice with respect to mongoDB deployment / configuration in this context?

Comment: A closely related question is that if you do set up multiple databases within a single mongoDB instance, can they be sharded across multiple servers?  If so, can we expect inbound queries, network consumption, etc, to be load-balanced across databases?